# Обновление страницы без перехода на нее?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

Уважаемые члены сообщества, прошу помочь в понимании следующего, имею родительскую страницу index.jsp, с нее по ссылке ухожу на другую страницу к примеру reg.jsp (index.jsp остается открытой вкладкой).
На reg.jsp пользователь регистся и закрывает страницу

```
window.close().
```

На индексе вывожу сессию с именем пользователя и с прочими его данными которые записала в reg.jsp. И тут мне нужно чтобы эти данные появились без перезагрузки индекса от пользователя. Как это сделать?

```
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL)
```

не пойдет так как он открывает новое окно, а мне нужно в уже открытой index.jsp. 
Такое вообще возможно? У кого какие мысли на сей счет имеются?

**index где хочу получить данные о пользователе:**

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
<p>Wellcome! Пользователь: <c:out value="${sessionScope.userid}"/><br/>
Забронированное время: <c:out value="${sessionScope.timeCookie}" /></p>
```

**index откуда открываю новое окно:**

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr style="cursor:pointer " onMouseOver="this.style.background='#FFCC33'"
        onMouseOut="this.style.background='white'"
        onClick="window.open('TimeServlet?action=listUser&userId=<c:out value="${user.mastername}"/> ','newwindow', 'width=600,height=650')">
        <td><c:out value="${user.mastername}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.masterlastname}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.mastersphone}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.masteravatar}" /></td>       
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**В новом окне reg.jsp провожу регистрацию.**

**после регистрации, закрываю новое окно:**

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
<H1>Уважаемый <c:out value="${sessionScope.userid}"/> </H1><br/>
Ваше время забронировано на: <c:out value="${sessionScope.timeCookie}" /></p>
<form method="POST" action='TimeServlet' name="but">
<button type="submit" name="button" value="button2" onClick="self.close()">Close</button>
</form>
```

Comment: В сторону AJAX уже копали?

Comment: А перезагрузку браузера со стороны сервера без участия пользователя можно сделать?

Comment: AJAX в любом случае подразумевает, что пользователь что то делает на этой странице, у меня случай другой, пользователь вносит данные на другой странице. То есть да, пользователь может обновить страницу и все данные о нем выдут, но хотелось бы вариант с обновлением без участия пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Открывая окно вы можете получить к нему доступ

```
var regWindow = window.open(....);
```

Соответственно вы можете получить событие закрытия данного окна.
По событию вы можете перезагрузить текущее окно, вызвавшее открытие, или отправить запрос куда вам нужно.
Для детального ответа очень мало представлено данных.

Comment: Андрей, немного кода указала в вопросе

Comment: @VikaSmirnova тем более, что вы работаете с окнами в своёй доменной зоне. Самый минимальный пример передачи данных. https://yadi.sk/d/UbLCVP6h3TiTQF

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/nwV7_qgn3TiUPm